# pebble-sdk - are applications for pebble STEEL transferable to TIME

Tags: time, multiplatform, pebble-sdk

I need to write a Pebble simple application and I need to know if I can develop it once for both Pebble STEEL and TIME. So far I have theoretical background found here http://developer.getpebble.com/sdk/migration-guide/.
Is it enough to simply use defines (PBL_PLATFORM_APLITE , PBL_PLATFORM_BASALT, ...) to get app working on both devices?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes! From an API standpoint there aren't very many differences between the basalt and aplite platforms, but when there are you can easily use `#ifdef` to handle it.